# SwitchMap operator with an array

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to learn rxjs and the Observable concept in general and have a scenario where I have a class of `<Room>{}` where `<Player>{}` can join in many-to-many relationship style.

In Firestore I have collection of `rooms` where each room has a property called `players` which is an array of user `uid`s.

When a rooms component is created I subscribe to `_roomService.getPlayersInRoom(roomId)` which looks like below:

```ts
getPlayersInRoom(roomId: string) {
  return this._db.doc<Room>(`rooms/${roomId}`).valueChanges().pipe(
    map(room => room.players),
    switchMap(players => players),//2
    switchMap(playerId => {
      if(playerId) {
        return this._db.doc<Player>(`users/${playerId}`).valueChanges();
      }
    })
  );
}
```

I subscribe to it later with

```ts
.subscribe(player => {
    if (player) {
      this.players = new Array();
      this.players.push(player);
    }
```

There are couple of issues here.  My observable does not return an array of players as expected (see line //2 which transforms the string[] into a string)

Another issues is that I new up the `this.players` array in my component every time that room changes (otherwise the `.push()` will push in duplicates.

I've read documentation on some of these operators and I understand them somewhat but not enough to figure out why this code is not behaving the way it should.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, `switchMap` expects you to return an Observable. If its an array-like value — it will turn it into an array using `from` (see this [`from` example](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/from/)).

If you really want to get an array back on the stream — you should return a stream, e.g. using [`of`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/of/): `switchMap(value => of([]))`

Yet, in your case, you want to substitute each id in the array with a stream. We'll need to use a [`combineLatest` operator](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/combineLatest/), for example (the name speaks for itself). Each array of players we will switch to a new stream. This new stream we'll combine of latest values on `valueChanges()` streams.

Heres an example:

```ts
getPlayersInRoom(roomId: string) {
    return this._db.doc<Room>(`rooms/${roomId}`).valueChanges().pipe(
      map(room => room.players),
      switchMap(players => {
        // turn array of player IDs
        // into array of streams of changes
        const playersStreams = players.map(
          playerId => this._db.doc<Player>(`users/${playerId}`).valueChanges()
        );

        // combine latest changes from all streams in that array
        return combineLatest(...playersStreams);
      })
    );
  }
```

Then in the subscription `players` would be an array of combined values from `valueChanges()`.

```ts
getPlayersInRoom(5)
  .subscribe(players => {
    this.players = players;
  })
```

Please, note that there are more ways to merge values from multiple `valueChanges()`. Most common are: `forkJoin` and `zip`

And there are more methods to [map a value on a stream](https://thinkrx.io/gist/ba116f84fe9f1493b989902c0927bb35)

Hope this helps

Comment: You're awesome!

Comment: @ska-dev, glad to help :)