# Angular Firestore combineLatest with multiple queries

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a little trouble with Angular9, Firestore6 and the `combineLatest` rxjs operator.

I have one collection of `users`, and another collection of `items`. One user can have several items, but in an old fashioned manyToMany relationship way, in which the items are master data (non modifiable) and the bridge table joins both collections with additional data:

- items

  - apple

    - name: "apple"
    - color: "green"
- user

  - items

    - uid

      - uid: "apple"
      - quantity: 23

So I need to get a list of the items of the logged in `user`, joining both collections:

- user

  - items

    - uid

      - uid: "apple"
      - quantity: 23
      - join

        - name: "apple"
        - color: "green"

This is my code:

```js
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';

getUserItems() {
  return this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.angularFirestore.collection<any>(`users/${user.uid}/items`).valueChanges()
          .pipe(
            switchMap(userItems=> {
              return combineLatest([
                of(userItems),
                userItems.map(userItem=> this.angularFirestore.doc<any>(`items/${userItem}`).valueChanges())
              ])
            }),
            map(([userItems, items]) => {
              console.log(userItems, items);
              return userItems.map(userItem => {
                return {
                  ...userItem,
                  join: items.find(item => item.uid === userItem.uid)
                }
              })
            })
          )
      }
    })
  )
}
```

But in the `map(([userItems, items])`, instead of `[any[], any[]]`, I get `[any[], Observable<any>]`, it does not compile because `Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'`.

I guess it's because the second `.valueChanges()` is not getting resolved, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me out?

I already tried other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55694693/switchmap-operator-with-an-array) but with no luck so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, you just need to add a spread operator to the `userItems.map` and you need to get the `itemId` (just a guess) from the userItem object:

```
return combineLatest([
  of(userItems),
  ...userItems.map(
    userItem => this.angularFirestore.doc<any(`items/${userItem.itemId}`).valueChanges()
  )
])
```

The `combineLatest` wants an array of `Observables`. Let's ignore the `of(userItems)` If you just do:

```
combineLatest([
  userItems.map((userItem) => this.af.valueChanges())
])
```

You will end up with an array inside of an array, so basically `Observable[][]`. That's why you need to use the spread operator, to put the items in the surrounding array. If you did not have the `of(userItems)`, you could have just done:

```
combineLatest(
  userItems.map((userItem) => this.af.valueChanges())
)
```

So without the wrapping array, but because you need the `userItems` as well, it's a nice solution to add them to the top.

I do however noticed a couple of other mistakes, which will probably not make it work for you. The `items` in the last map, is just one item, and not an array. To get it into the array you expect, you again need to use the spread operator, which in this case is a rest operator, on the items parameter, like this:

```
map(([userItems, ...items]) => {
```

Comment: That was it, now it's working as expected. Thank you very much! @pierreduc can you please elaborate on _why_ is the spread operator needed to actually resolve the Observable into an Object inside the `combineLatest()` operator?